# Getting all loaded nodes from ExtJS Tree

Tags: javascript, extjs, tree

I'm looking for a way to get all loaded nodes from a tree store, even those whose parents are COLLAPSED. Right now the store contains only the "visible" records, i.e. all the nodes that are either expanded or leaf nodes. Is there a way to get all the loaded nodes (even leaf nodes whose parents are collapsed)? It seems there is no method that returns such an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the default behavior of an asynchronous tree: it only loads children when user expands the parent. You must send the complete tree from the server to access  all nodes through the tree store.

Comment: The children are actually loaded but the parent is collapsed. Scenario: I have a parent node called parent1. I expand it. The server brings the child nodes etc. I edit some of the child nodes since they are checkbox nodes. Then I collapse parent1 and move on to parent2 etc. After I've edited all the leaf nodes needed, I want to be able to access all previously loaded but now collapsed parent nodes and their children. They are not lost since when I re-expand the parent there is no server call and the leaf node state remains the same (i.e. they are checked or unchecked).

Comment: Then you can find them all in the store or you ca iterate from the root with `cascade` method.

Comment: I haven't tried `cascadeBy` but both `getData()` and `eachChild` only bring the 'visible' nodes, not the children of collapsed parents.

Comment: If cascadeBy doesn't do the job then it's a bug.

Comment: Tried `cascadeBy` starting from the root node and it worked. Thanks!